# Asp.net WebApi 2 File upload with Model Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

Project is ( .net Framework 4.6.1 on Azure)
Does anyone know if there is a way to use a Controller to accept both file upload and a model entity (Json) in the same request. Client app needs to upload a file, as well as metadata about the file and we would like to do it in one request if possible.

I have thought of 2 possibilities:

1. Post the File(s), and the individual model fields ( model is flat) as if it were a web form so build my model object from the form by hand. ( a la https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)
2. Post the File(s) and the model object as another json file and de-serialize into my model object as part of a custom MultipartMemoryStreamProvider

Am I missing an option?
TIA

Comment: Depending on how many fields are in your metadata, you can add custom headers to your request, as option 3.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is just adding the file to the model or creating a ViewModel with both the data and the file in it. Due to data binding, as long as your input fields in the client are the same name, that data will be mapped to the object during the request.

Model:

```
public class yourModel
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    ...
    //other data

    public IFormFile yourFile {get;set;} //your file
    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("YourRoute")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<WhateverYouWantToReturn> YourAction(yourModel model)
{
     //set a breakpoint here to see if your fields populated
     ...
     //do something with your model
     ...
     return WhateverYouWantToReturn;
}
```

View:
As long as the name of your input fields match the names of your fields in your object, they should map.

```
<form enctype="multipart/formdata" method="post" action="/your/route">
     <input type="text" name="name"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="somesHiddenField" value="yourValue" />
     ... <!-- Whatever other fields you need. -->
     <input type="file" name="yourFile"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```